# Wrong reputation calculation

Tags: discussion

I have reached the limit of getting reputation today. (for the first time :D). However, it seems some calculations gone wrong. Take a look at this image:

[image: rep]

As you can see, I got `195 + 5 + 2` reputation today. Also one unaccepted answer so I lost 15 rep here.

1. Why I'm not getting more rep? If the calculation is right (`187 rep`) I didn't reach the limit of 200 yet.

2- I've earned total of `202` rep here. Why I'm not getting Mortarboard badge?

3- I'm not terrible at math. I know `195 + 5 + 2 - 15 = 187` but I didn't get down voted. Some one just unaccepted the answer. Fair enough. This means I just lost some rep, but this doesn't mean I didn't earn 200 rep.

Comment: 1) Accepts/Unaccepts don't count toward the rep cap. So, losing 15 rep to that does not count for letting you earn more rep for the day from upvoting. 2) Pretty sure that badge is given in a batch, but I could be wrong. 3) You earned 200 rep _from upvotes_ which, which means you _did_ hit the rep count. Now if you fell to 187 from _downvotes_ rather than the unaccept, some of those upvotes that didn't give you rep would have started to. (I will likely post this as an answer in a few minutes, just want to check a couple things right quick to make sure I'm not crazy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems fine to me.

From upvotes alone you earned 200 reputation, which is the maximum you can from upvotes.  Reputation gains from accepting an answer or having your answer accepted [do not count against the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), so the fact that you lost 15 reputation (and gained 2 reputation) from this action doesn't factor into the upvote limit.

Comment: hmm. seems fair but i didnt earned that badge :/ which is somehow disappointing. but i deal with this some how!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You should receive the badge for this day. It's not immediate though. Give it some time.

Answer (score 3):

The reputation feed on your profile really does a poor job of reflecting your daily reputation, especially when you have reversals or unaccepts in the mix.

The feed shows "reputation events" on the day that the event happened.  But anytime you have a reversal event (where reputation you earned is removed), the reputation is actually treated as if it was never earned (so it actually counts against the day you first received the rep).

Take the unaccept you have today for example.  You earned +15 yesterday when the answer was originally accepted.  Today, the OP decided another answer was better an unaccepted your answer.  The -15 shows up as a rep lose in your profile today, but for purposes of the database and badges, it actually counts against your reputation your earned yesterday.  It is effectively treated like it never happened.